# Insert com acentos no Oracle

Tags: oracle, codificação-de-caracteres, acentuação

Quando eu faço um `INSERT` por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO TESTE (NOME) VALUES ('INSCRIÇÃO ESTADUAL');
```

Está salvando na tabela dessa forma:

> INSCRI����O ESTADUAL

E na tela exibe `"INSCRIÃÃO ESTADUAL"`.

Estou utilizando o **Oracle SQL Developer**, quando eu entro na tabela e altero na mão, ai sim salva corretamente:

> INSCRI��O ESTADUAL

E na tela exibe corretamente `"INSCRIÇÃO ESTADUAL"`.

#### Configuração do NLS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Executando `SELECT PARAMETER, VALUE FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até olhei a configuração do meu `NLS` e aparentemente está ok, existe alguma forma de alterar o encoding na hora do INSERT?

Comment: Qual o output de "SELECT PARAMETER, VALUE FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS"?

Comment: @bruno Nesse caso o charset está `NLS_CHARACTERSET US7ASCII`

Comment: @bruno Alterei a pergunta com todos valores

Comment: A resposta em baixo do Paulo Roberto ajudou?

Comment: @bruno Não, continua inserindo da forma incorreta, até dei um `echo $NLS_LANG`, mostra que eu alterei só que não influência em nada no meu Oracle

Comment: Podes confirmar se eu percebi: No Oracle SQL Developer, quando executas a instrução de INSERT os caracteres não estão a ser guardados correctamente, mas quando editas a tabela eles são guardados com os acentos?

Comment: Exatamente @bruno

Comment: Você está inserindo por onde? É um sistema? Se for uma página, não pode ser o encoding da mesma? No HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Talvez, isso resolva o seu problema, se não resolver cocloque o erro ai que vams buscar juntos a solução.
Crie uma variável de ambiente chamada NLS_LANG, com o valor .WE8ISO8859P1. Conforme figura abaixo.

[image: Insert com acentos no Oracle]

Se não resolver leia este artigo: http://www.fabioprado.net/2012/11/configurando-national-language-support.html

Comment: Aqui não funcionou, eu uso `Ubuntu` e até dei um `export` na variável, defini no "profile", encerrei a sessão e testei novamente... não adiantou :/

Answer (score 1):

Use variáveis de ambiente NLS_LANG para configurar corretamente, pois ele deve estar entrando como ASCII (7 bits), use export para Linux e set para Windows.

Se o dado de entrada estiver codificado em ambiente Windows:

```
export/set NLS_LANG='AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252'
```

Em ISO-8859-P1 (Unix):

```
`export/set NLS_LANG='AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1'`
```

Em UTF-8:

```
export/set NLS_LANG='AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8'
```

Comment: Lucas eu fiz isso, foi a mesma coisa que o Paulo Roberto sugeriu, eu até adicionei no `~profile` além de fazer o export na hora também e nada. Dentro do Sql Developer não pega.

Comment: Podes fazer um teste no sql*plus, só para confirmar se é problema do sql developer, ou se é problema das variáveis de ambiente do linux.

Answer (score 1):

Tive um problema parecido, quando ia utilizar um client oracle via docker, os registros inseridos que continha acentos ficavam todos bagunçados, só consegui resolver exportando a varivel NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8