# Caracteres estranhos sendo inseridos no insert Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho um banco de dados oracle XE, quero importar scripts em sql para preencher as tabelas, porém, os caracteres com acento e Ç por exemplo ficam com caracteres estranhos � por exemplo. Nesse insert de exemplo:

```
Insert into PESSOA   (ID, TIPO, CPF_CNPJ, RAZAO_SOCIAL,      
        NOME_FANTASIA, RG_INSC_ESTADUAL, LOGRADOURO, 
        NUMERO, CEP, BAIRRO, NOME_CONTATO, TELEFONE_1,
        TELEFONE_2, EMAIL, CIDADE_ID) 
Values    
        (170, 'J', '12010779000105', 'MOTO BOX PEÇAS E
         ACESSÓRIOS LTDA', 'MOTO BOX',  '040000052 ', 
        'RUA VISCONDE DE NHAUMA', '315', 
        '55012010', 'MAURICIO DE NASSAU', 
        'CÉLIO', '(81) 3723-0455', '(81) 3721- 5571',
        'lucycouto@uol.com.br', 1509);
```

Quando consulto os tipos de caracteres padrão tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';  

Resultado =  AL16UTF16

SELECT value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

AL32UTF8
```

Devo alterar algo para importar corretamente o sql?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69300/

Comment: Tirou minhas duvidas, obg

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Insert com acentos no Oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69300/insert-com-acentos-no-oracle)