# Banco de dados trocando acento por "?"

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

No meu PL/SQL todos os acentos estão sendo trocados por "?".

Exemplo de um comentário de uma tabela:

> Flag indicador de dispositivo legal ser???? usado no termo de embrargo ou nao. Valores poss????veis: 1 - Sim  ou 0 - Nao. Default: 1

Quando crio uma tabela direto nele funciona a acentuação, porém quando copio um script de um bloco de texto por exemplo e colo no PL/SQL e mando criar as tabelas fica desse jeito.

Como consertar isso?

Comment: O problema é de encode do banco... Não me lembro ao certo quais estão disponíveis no oracle... Quando trabalhei com ele tinha o encode do banco e do campo da tabela... Procure alterar para UTF-8

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Insert com acentos no Oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69300/insert-com-acentos-no-oracle)

Comment: Não é duplicata, visto que o problema do post mencionado nao foi resolvido e a pessoa usa Sql developer, estou usando PLSQL.

Comment: Veja se esta resposta te ajuda: [Ajuda](http://glufke.net/oracle/viewtopic.php?t=8742)

Comment: Qual codificação(Ex:UTF-8) e linguagem do banco de dados (Ex: InnoDB) você está usando ?

Comment: Erick Luz, algum comando para ver isso ?

Comment: Veja as configurações assim: SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;

Comment: NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET : AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET : WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_LANGUAGE : AMERICAN

Comment: O seu script tem que estar com a condificação UTF-8. Você consegue alterar usando o notepad++ por exemplo. Vai em "formatar", depois seleciona a opção "Converter para UTF-8 (sem BOM)". Salva a alteração e testa de novo pra ver se deu certo! :)

Answer (score 1):

Conforme eu havia sugerido nos comentários, você pode usar essa consulta pra ver as configurações do seu BD Oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;
```

Seu banco está com as configurações:

> NLS_CHARACTERSET : WE8MSWIN1252
>   NLS_LANGUAGE : AMERICAN

Provavelmente apenas alterando o NLS_CHARACTERSET de **WE8MSWIN1252** para **WE8ISO8859P1** o problema já será resolvido.

Encontrei o seguinte comando para altera-lo:

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP MOUNT;
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
ALTER SYSTEM SET JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET WE8ISO8859P1;
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP;
```

Mas **cuidado**, fazer essa alteração pode corromper dados do seu BD.

Segue alguns links para consulta:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_characterset.htm

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779159/change-nls-character-set-parameters-on-oracle-11g-xe

Comment: Caro George posso estar enganado, mas creio que o iso-8859-1 não é quase equivalente ao windows-1252? Creio que o problema dele seja com UTF-8. Creio que quando o autor falou de PL/SQL ele se referia ao "PL/SQL editor", então acho melhor cobrar antes esclarecimentos do autor antes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento iso-8859-1 e win-1252 são praticamente iguais. O que muda essencialmente é que no 1252 se usa a faixa `0x80` a `0x9F`, que é reservada no ISO

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tem razão sobre o editor PL/SQL, fazia tempo que não acessava essa questão e respondi sem prestar atenção no detalhe. Ele informa que criando a tabela "direto" ele consegue por acento. Acho ainda que a resposta pode ser útil pra quem cair aqui pelo título, vc acha melhor remover? Se sim, sem problema, só me avisar aqui.

Comment: Caro George, não é questão de remover, a questão é um problema provavelmente de unicode, windows-1252 ou iso-8859-1 não são unicode, o problema do autor é outra coisa, eu acho que você deve editar a resposta e responder a exatamente o que é necessário para a pergunta, assim salvando a pergunta a resposta. Você pode aguardar um feedback do autor da pergunta, é provavel que o autor venha esclarecer para ti o problema, mas cobre dele, e de todos, que fizerem perguntas assim, com falta de informação [...]

Comment: [...] Aliais talvez o melhor sempre seja votar em fechar e aguardar a pessoa editar a pergunta esclarecendo para que seja possivel "salva-la". Até outra hora.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar/alterar uma variável no Windows para corrigir este problema. Para isto, execute uma query que verifica quais são os valores em uso:

**SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters**

A sua variável de ambiente será definida a partir dos valores obtidos:
**<NLS_LANGUAGE>_<NLS_TERRITORY>.<NLS_CHARACTERSET>**

Por exemplo: **NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1**

Cada versão do Windows tem um roteiro para criar ou alterar uma variável de ambiente, algo como Painel de controle -> Sistema  -> Configurações avançadas do sistema  -> Variáveis de ambiente do Windows.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).